# What works faster "for(key in obj)" or ".forEach"?

Tags: javascript

What calculation operations faster?

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
   // do something with obj[key]
});
```

or

```
for(key in obj){
    // The key is key
    // The value is obj[key]
}
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ - find out :D

Comment: http://jsperf.com/diy-1234 `for..in`, obviously. No function calls involved.

Comment: The two are not equal, but clearly the first is doing more work. Why? Do you have a performance issue in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference is based on what is the Array structure you are working on. The for (key in obj) iterates through the enumerable properties of the object and specifically usefull for [Sparse Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array).

For example,

```
var keyInArr;
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "val1";
arr[10] = "val2";
arr[100] = "val3";
for (keyInArr in arr) {

}
```

For the array above we iterate only 3 times, not 101 times.

The forEach function, on the contrary, will 'loop through them all'. So, as I mentioned, it depends on the structure of the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing test case for this on jsperf.

http://jsperf.com/angularjs-foreach-vs-native-foreach/31